# How do you enable debug logging for WebRTC in Objective-C

Tags: webrtc

I'm trying to track down an issue with data channels ([WebRTC data channel not connecting or no callbacks being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823880/webrtc-data-channel-not-connecting-or-no-callbacks-being-called/26919212)) and am just not getting enough information about what is going wrong.  Does debug logging have to be compiled in?

I remember previously I could use:

```
talk_base::LogMessage::LogThreads();
talk_base::LogMessage::LogTimestamps();
talk_base::LogMessage::LogToDebug(talk_base::LS_DEBUG);
```

to set debugging from Libjingle.  Is there an equivalent for the Objective-C API?

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the logs in xcode console

```
#import <WebRTC/RTCLogging.h>
#import <WebRTC/RTCMetrics.h>

RTCSetMinDebugLogLevel(RTCLoggingSeverityInfo); 
RTCEnableMetrics();
```

In order to show the logs in file as output

```
self.fileLogger = [[RTCFileLogger alloc] initWithDirPath:logsDirectory maxFileSize:(100 * 1024)];         
self.fileLogger.severity = kRTCFileLoggerSeverityInfo;
[self.fileLogger start];
```

Comment: hi, any solution for android?

Comment: @famfamfam Add a logger when initializing WebRTC on android: PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(appContext).setInjectableLogger( /* ... */)